# PSR-2 namespace Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Database' not found

Tags: php

I'm currently learning the PSR-2 standard, the namespace has me confused as it's causing the following error in my browser, ** Fatal error: Cannot declare class Database\Database because the name is already in use in /var/www/html/config/database.php on line 6** if anyone could help me I would really appreciate it, thank you very much

Edit: I'm getting this new error, ** Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Database\PDO' not found in /var/www/html/config/database.php:18 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/login.php(19): Database\Database->getConnection() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/config/database.php on line 18**

```
<?php
namespace Database;

use Database;

class Database
{
    private $host = "";
    private $db_name = "";
    private $username = "";
    private $password = "";
    public $conn;

    public function getConnection()
    {

        $this->conn = null;

        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
        } catch (PDOException $exception) {
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the `use Database`, this is the Database class, you don't need to `use` it here

Comment: @JensV thank you - that cleared that error, but i'm getting a new error which I've pasted above, I've tried to google it but couldn't find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in the `Database` namespace. So your `new PDO` is looking for `Database\PDO`.

To get around this you need to use PDO from the root namespace by using `new \PDO`

Comment: thank you so much, that had me baffled for hours, i really appreciate your time